# How does the reverse function in SAS work?

Tags: sas

I have a time data field, say, 10/1/2014.
I want to extract the month and the year information dynamically in SAS, given any date.

I wrote the following code in SAS to extract the month info:

```
month = substr(time_field, 1, index(time_field, '/')-1);
```

This worked fine.

I wrote the following snippet to extract the year info:

```
year = substr(reverse(time_field), 1, 4);
```

This doesn't work; it throws a blank. Have I missed something? Please help.

Comment: Can you not use the `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions in SAS? [SAS Date, Time, and Datetime Values](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lrcon/zenid-63.htm)

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I could; but I fail to understand why I couldn't get it here. Am I using the "reverse" function right? I'm curious.

Comment: 1) You write that you have a *time* field - do you mean a *date* field? 2) After reversing the string, remember that you have to reverse it again to get the digits in the correct order. 3) If you [converted it to ISO8601 format](https://communities.sas.com/thread/60819) then the year would be the first four characters. P.S. I know nothing of SAS.

Comment: In addition to the excellent advice Reese and Salva give you below, I would remind you that character and numeric values shouldn't be treated cavalierly like this.  Either your data is a string ("01/01/2014") and you can do the above, *or* you can do MONTH, YEAR, etc. - but you shouldn't do both.  Figure out what variable type it is and do the proper one.

Answer (score 1):

SAS will return the year for you.  No need to write any custom function for this purpose. Look:

```
data _null_;
    length year 4.;
    year=year(today());
    put "we are on the year of " year;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable has trailing spaces most likely. So when you reverse it, the trailing spaces become leading spaces and then you take the first four characters which are blanks.

You can verify this by running the reverse function alone on the variable and see the results.
Try adding the compress function.

```
year = substr(reverse(compress(time_field)), 1, 4);
```

Though this may solve your problem, you should really convert your date to a SAS date and then use the Month/Day/Year functions.

```
data have;
    length time_field $20.;
    time_field="10/1/2014";

    year_bad = substr(reverse(time_field),1, 4);
    year_good = reverse(substr(reverse(compress(time_field)),1, 4));
    year_better = year(input(time_field, mmddyy10.));
    put "year_bad:" year_bad;
    put "year_good:" year_good;
    put "year_better:" year_better;

run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is either a month in a *character* field, or it is a numeric value *formatted* as a date.  While you can use text expressions on numerics, you shouldn't; you should explicitly convert them.

When you don't, then you end up with things like this - ie, improper lengths of fields, because the automatic conversion is very loose.  It tends to allow a huge amount of extra space where it's not required to.

If your data is numeric, use MONTH() or YEAR() and be done with it; there's no reason to play in text here.  Look at the field in the data explorer; it will tell you if it's numeric or not.  (Numeric with a format can still look like text, so actually look at it!)

If your data is text, then you have some better options than REVERSE.

First is SCAN.  `SCAN` splits by word, similar to many other languages; often `strsplit` (R) or similar.

```
month=scan(mdy_var,1,'/');
day  =scan(mdy_var,2,'/');
year =scan(mdy_var,3,'/');
```

Second, you could still use `SUBSTR`, along with `LENGTH`.

```
year = scan(mdy_var,length(mdy_var)-3,4);
```

`LENGTH` tells you how long the string really is (minus trailing spaces), so '10/1/2014' is 9 long; 6th character (9-3) is the 2, and then 4 characters after that [which should be unnecessary].  This method wouldn't really work with Day, of course, only with year (and only with 4 digit year).  Scan is better really, but this is a good example of how this works.

Going along the same lines, you can use FIND and look backwards, also, using a negative start position.

```
year = substr(mdy_var,find(mdy_var,'/',-99)+1,4);
```

That starts it at the 99th character (which is realistically your maximum, right?) and goes left, and then tells you what position the first '/' it finds.